# Load modernizr in head but use it in require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, modernizr

I want to load modernizr synchronously in head to prevent a fouc. I am using require.js at before /body to load some other scripts in which I'd like to use modernizr for feature detection and such things.

What is the right way to do this or is it even recommended to do so?
If I require modernizr in my scripts it gets loaded again, if I won't, it is undefined.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If Modernizr is the 1st script loaded in head, then it is accessible from everywhere, so you can define simple wrapper like this:

```
define('modernizr', function () { return window.Modernizr });
```

This code may be put inside `wrappers.js` like this:

```
<head>
<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>   
<script src="/js/vendor/require.js"></script>  
<script src="/js/wrappers.js"></script>  
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then in main.js

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
  , src = scripts[scripts.length - 1].src
  , baseUrl = src.substring(src.indexOf(document.location.pathname), src.lastIndexOf('/'))

require.config({
  baseUrl: baseUrl
})
```

Comment: Would you define this in just after your require config declaration?  Or would you have something like a wrappers.js file and have lots of these little defines?  I could see a use here everytime you want to return something from the window object.  Especially for testing then you'd be able to mock out the global object really easily

Comment: For the op question, I would place it right after require config in main.js specified in 'data-main' attribute that is loaded by requirejs automatically. But if you need to put it in separate file, then these scripts should be loaded in correct order and main.js should define baseUrl.